# Spring Batch file writing job doesn't stop and keeps running

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, infinite-loop, file-generation

I have a sample Spring Boot/Batch job I'm assembling together by adopting several online examples that is intended to simulate the generation of an [ACH formatted file](https://achdevguide.nacha.org/ach-file-overview#:%7E:text=An%20ACH%20file%20is%20a,must%20follow%20a%20specific%20order.).  I can see the file gets generated, but the job never finishes and the output file keeps growing and never gets released even though the job is only configured to write **minimal (1) record** in ACH specific output format:

[image]

The record production keeps looping endlessly.

Here are the relevant configurations, in which it could be seen how the file output is facilitated by a set of ACH record type specific extractors and aggregators and their composition:

```
    /**
 * 
 */
package com.***.nacha.producer.config;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldExtractor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FormatterLineAggregator;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.LineAggregator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

import com.***.nacha.producer.domain.ACHBatchRecord;
import com.***.nacha.producer.domain.ACHBatchRecordControl;
import com.***.nacha.producer.domain.ACHBatchRecordEntry;
import com.***.nacha.producer.domain.ACHBatchRecordHeader;
import com.***.nacha.producer.domain.ACHFileControl;
import com.***.nacha.producer.domain.ACHFileHeader;
import com.***.nacha.producer.domain.ACHFileRecord;
import com.***.nacha.producer.domain.ACHRecord;

/**
 * @author x123456
 *
 */
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    private Map<String, LineAggregator> aggregators = new HashMap<>();
    
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        aggregators.put("ACHFileHeader", JobConfiguration.this.achFileHeaderAggregator());
        aggregators.put("ACHBatchRecordHeader", JobConfiguration.this.achBatchHeaderAggregator());
        aggregators.put("ACHBatchRecordEntry", JobConfiguration.this.achBatchEntryAggregator());
        aggregators.put("ACHBatchRecordControl", JobConfiguration.this.achBatchControlAggregator());
        aggregators.put("ACHFileControl", JobConfiguration.this.achFileControlAggregator());
    };

    
    @Bean
    public LineAggregator<ACHFileRecord> achLineAggregator() {
        return new LineAggregator<ACHFileRecord>() {
            
           

            private String aggregate(ACHRecord record) {
                return aggregate(record, false);
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            private String aggregate(ACHRecord record, boolean isLastRecord) {
                
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                sb.append(JobConfiguration.this.aggregators.get(record.getClass().getSimpleName()).aggregate(record));
                if (!isLastRecord) {
                    sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }

            

            @Override
            public String aggregate(ACHFileRecord item) {
                if (item == null) {
                    return "";
                }
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                sb.append(this.aggregate(item.getFileHeader()));

                for (ACHBatchRecord batch : item.getBatchRecords()) {
                    sb.append(this.aggregate(batch.getAchBatchRecordHeader()));

                    for (ACHBatchRecordEntry batchEntry : batch.getAchBatchRecordEntries()) {
                        sb.append(this.aggregate(batchEntry));
                    }

                    sb.append(this.aggregate(batch.getAchBatchRecordControl()));
                }
                
                    sb.append(this.aggregate(item.getFileControl(), true));
                
                
                
                

                return sb.toString();

            }

        };

    }

    

    @Bean
    //@Scope("prototype")
    public FormatterLineAggregator<ACHFileHeader> achFileHeaderAggregator() {
        FormatterLineAggregator<ACHFileHeader> lineAggregator = new FormatterLineAggregator<>();
        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(achFileHeaderWrapperFieldExtractor());
        lineAggregator.setFormat("%1.1s%2.2s%10.10s%10.10s%6.6s%4.4s%1.1s%03d%2.2s%1.1s%-23.23s%-23.23s%8.8s");
        return lineAggregator;
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope("prototype")
    public FieldExtractor<ACHFileHeader> achFileHeaderWrapperFieldExtractor() {
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<ACHFileHeader> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] {
                "recordTypeCode", "priorityCode", "immediateDestination", "immediateOrigin", "fileCreationDate",
                "fileCreationTime", "fileIdModifier", "recordSize", "blockingFactor", "formatCode",
                "immediateDestinationName", "immediateOriginName", "referenceCode" });
        return fieldExtractor;
    }

//--
    @Bean
    //@Scope("prototype")
    public FormatterLineAggregator<ACHBatchRecordHeader> achBatchHeaderAggregator() {
        FormatterLineAggregator<ACHBatchRecordHeader> lineAggregator = new FormatterLineAggregator<>();
        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(achBatchHeaderWrapperFieldExtractor());
        lineAggregator.setFormat("%1.1s%3.3s%-16.16s%-20.20s%10d%3.3s%10.10s%6.6s%6.6s%3.3s%1.1s%08d%07d");
        return lineAggregator;
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope("prototype")
    public FieldExtractor<ACHBatchRecordHeader> achBatchHeaderWrapperFieldExtractor() {
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<ACHBatchRecordHeader> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] {
                "recordTypeCode", "serviceClassCode", "companyName", "companyDiscretionaryData", "companyId",
                "standardEntryClassCode", "companyEntryDescription", "companyDescriptiveDate", "effectiveEntryDate",
                "settlementDate", "originatorStatusCode", "originationDfiId", "batchNumber" });
        return fieldExtractor;
    }

//--
    @Bean
    //@Scope("prototype")
    public FormatterLineAggregator<ACHBatchRecordEntry> achBatchEntryAggregator() {
        FormatterLineAggregator<ACHBatchRecordEntry> lineAggregator = new FormatterLineAggregator<>();
        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(achBatchEntryWrapperFieldExtractor());
        lineAggregator.setFormat("%1.1s%2d%08d%1d%-17d%010d%-15.15s%-22.22s%2.2s%1.1s%015d");
        return lineAggregator;
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope("prototype")
    public FieldExtractor<ACHBatchRecordEntry> achBatchEntryWrapperFieldExtractor() {
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<ACHBatchRecordEntry> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] {
                "recordTypeCode", "transactionCode", "receivingDfiId", "checkDigit", "dfiAcctNbr", "amount",
                "individualIdNbr", "individualName", "discretionaryData", "addendaRecordInd", "traceNumber" });
        return fieldExtractor;
    }

//---
    @Bean
    //@Scope("prototype")
    public FormatterLineAggregator<ACHBatchRecordControl> achBatchControlAggregator() {
        FormatterLineAggregator<ACHBatchRecordControl> lineAggregator = new FormatterLineAggregator<>();
        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(achBatchControlWrapperFieldExtractor());
        lineAggregator.setFormat("%1.1s%3.3s%06d%010d%012d%012d%10d%19.19s%6.6s%08d%07d");
        return lineAggregator;
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope("prototype")
    public FieldExtractor<ACHBatchRecordControl> achBatchControlWrapperFieldExtractor() {
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<ACHBatchRecordControl> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] {
                "recordTypeCode", "serviceClassCode", "entryAddendaCount", "entryHash", "totDebitDollarAmt",
                "totCreditDollarAmt", "companyId", "messageAuthCode", "reserved", "originatingDfiId", "batchNumber" });
        return fieldExtractor;
    }

//---
    @Bean
    //@Scope("prototype")
    public FormatterLineAggregator<ACHFileControl> achFileControlAggregator() {
        FormatterLineAggregator<ACHFileControl> lineAggregator = new FormatterLineAggregator<>();
        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(achFileControlWrapperFieldExtractor());
        lineAggregator.setFormat("%1.1s%06d%06d%08d%010d%012d%012d%-39s");
        return lineAggregator;
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope("prototype")
    public FieldExtractor<ACHFileControl> achFileControlWrapperFieldExtractor() {
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<ACHFileControl> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] {
                "recordTypeCode", "batchCount", "blockCount", "entryAddendaCount", "entryHash", "totDebitDollarAmt",
                "totCreditDollarAmt", "reserved" });
        return fieldExtractor;
    }
    //=======
    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public FlatFileItemWriter<ACHFileRecord> achReportWriter() throws Exception {
        
        String outFilePath = "result.out";
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<ACHFileRecord>()
                .name("ACHrecordWriter")
                .lineAggregator(achLineAggregator())
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(outFilePath))
                .shouldDeleteIfExists(true)
                .shouldDeleteIfEmpty(true)
                .build();

        
    }

    @Bean
    //@StepScope
    public ItemReader<ACHFileRecord> itemReader() {
        return new MockACHFileRecordReader();
    }

    
    @Bean
    public Step step() throws Exception {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<ACHFileRecord, ACHFileRecord>chunk(1)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .writer(achReportWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step())
                .end()
                .build();
                
    }

}
```

The main class just enables batch processing:

```
package com.***.nacha.producer;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;

    @EnableBatchProcessing
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class NachaFileProductionApplication {
        
      
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(NachaFileProductionApplication.class, args);
        }
    
    }
```

There's some circular references handling configured to be taken care of in `application.properties`:

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

The item reader is using some [data fakery](https://www.datafaker.net/) to produce a record compliant to the specs mentioned above:

```
package com.***.nacha.producer.config;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.NonTransientResourceException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.UnexpectedInputException;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;

import com.***.nacha.producer.domain.ACHBatchRecord;
import com.***.nacha.producer.domain.ACHBatchRecordControl;
import com.***.nacha.producer.domain.ACHBatchRecordEntry;
import com.***.nacha.producer.domain.ACHBatchRecordHeader;
import com.***.nacha.producer.domain.ACHFileControl;
import com.***.nacha.producer.domain.ACHFileHeader;
import com.***.nacha.producer.domain.ACHFileRecord;

import net.datafaker.Company;
import net.datafaker.Faker;

/**
 * @author x123456
 *
 */
public class MockACHFileRecordReader implements ItemReader<ACHFileRecord> {

    private static final Faker faker = new Faker();
    private int globalEntriesCnt = 0;

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public ACHFileRecord read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

        int batchPerFileCnt = 1; //this.getRandomNumberBetween(8, 12);
        
        
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMdd");
        String originName = faker.company().name()+" National Bank";
        String destinationName = faker.company().name()+" Bank";
        
        
        
        
        
        ACHFileRecord file = new ACHFileRecord();                   //composite record, no need to populate
        
        ACHFileHeader fileHeader = new ACHFileHeader();             //populate randomly
        fileHeader.setRecordTypeCode('1');
        fileHeader.setPriorityCode("01");
        fileHeader.setImmediateDestination(faker.regexify("\\s{1}\\d{9}"));
        fileHeader.setImmediateOrigin(faker.regexify("\\s{1}\\d{9}"));
        fileHeader.setFileCreationDate(LocalDate.now().format(dateFormatter));
        fileHeader.setFileCreationTime(new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm").format(new Date()));
        fileHeader.setFileIdModifier(faker.regexify("[0-9A-Z]{1}"));
        fileHeader.setRecordSize(Long.parseLong("094"));
        fileHeader.setBlockingFactor("10");
        fileHeader.setFormatCode("1");
        fileHeader.setImmediateDestinationName(destinationName);
        fileHeader.setImmediateOriginName(originName);
        fileHeader.setReferenceCode("");
        
        file.setFileHeader(fileHeader);
        
        hydrateFileWithBatches(file, batchPerFileCnt);
        
        ACHFileControl fileFooter = new ACHFileControl();           //populate randomly
        fileFooter.setRecordTypeCode('9');
        fileFooter.setBatchCount(Long.valueOf(batchPerFileCnt));
        fileFooter.setBlockCount(Long.parseLong(faker.regexify("[0-9]{6}")));
        fileFooter.setEntryAddendaCount(Long.valueOf(globalEntriesCnt));
        fileFooter.setEntryHash(Long.parseLong(faker.regexify("\\d{10}")));
        fileFooter.setTotDebitDollarAmt(Long.parseLong(faker.regexify("\\d{12}")));
        fileFooter.setTotCreditDollarAmt(Long.parseLong(faker.regexify("\\d{12}")));
        fileFooter.setReserved(null);
        
        file.setFileControl(fileFooter);

        return file;
    }
    
    
    
    private ACHFileRecord hydrateFileWithBatches(final ACHFileRecord file, final int batchCount) {
        final int entryPerBatchCnt = 1; //this.getRandomNumberBetween(800, 1200);
        
        for (int i=0; i < batchCount; i++) {
            
            ACHBatchRecordHeader batchHeader = new ACHBatchRecordHeader();      //populate randomly
            
            Company company = faker.company();
            String companyName = company.name();
            int companyId = company.hashCode();
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMdd");
            Long batchNumber = Long.valueOf(i);
            Long originationDfiId = Long.parseLong(faker.regexify("(\\d{4})(\\d{4})"));
            
            batchHeader.setRecordTypeCode('5');
            batchHeader.setServiceClassCode(faker.expression("#{options.option '200', '220', '225'}"));
            batchHeader.setCompanyName(companyName);
            batchHeader.setCompanyDiscretionaryData(null);
            batchHeader.setCompanyId(Long.valueOf(companyId));
            batchHeader.setStandardEntryClassCode(faker.expression("#{options.option 'PPD', 'CCD'}"));
            batchHeader.setCompanyEntryDescription(faker.expression("#{options.option 'PAYROLL', 'PRENOTE', 'TAX PAYMNT', 'VENDOR PMT', '1099 PMT', 'CHILDSUPPT'}"));
            batchHeader.setCompanyDescriptiveDate("000000");
            batchHeader.setEffectiveEntryDate(LocalDate.now().format(formatter));
            batchHeader.setSettlementDate(null);
            batchHeader.setOriginatorStatusCode("1");
            batchHeader.setOriginationDfiId(originationDfiId);
            batchHeader.setBatchNumber(batchNumber);
            
            
            ACHBatchRecordControl batchFooter = new ACHBatchRecordControl();    //populate randomly
            batchFooter.setRecordTypeCode('8');
            batchFooter.setServiceClassCode(faker.expression("#{options.option '200', '220', '225'}"));
            batchFooter.setEntryAddendaCount(Long.parseLong(faker.regexify("\\d{6}")));
            batchFooter.setEntryHash(Long.parseLong(faker.regexify("\\d{10}")));
            batchFooter.setTotDebitDollarAmt(Long.parseLong(faker.regexify("\\d{10}\\d{2}")));
            batchFooter.setTotCreditDollarAmt(Long.parseLong(faker.regexify("\\d{10}\\d{2}")));
            batchFooter.setCompanyId(Long.valueOf(companyId));
            batchFooter.setMessageAuthCode(null);
            batchFooter.setReserved(null);
            batchFooter.setOriginatingDfiId(originationDfiId);
            batchFooter.setBatchNumber(batchNumber);
            
            
            
            ACHBatchRecord batch = new ACHBatchRecord();                        //composite record, no need to populate
            batch.setAchBatchRecordHeader(batchHeader);
            hydrateBatchWithEntries(batch, entryPerBatchCnt);
            batch.setAchBatchRecordControl(batchFooter);
            file.getBatchRecords().add(batch);
        }
        return file;
    }

    private ACHBatchRecord hydrateBatchWithEntries(final ACHBatchRecord batch, final int entryCount) {
        
       
       List<ACHBatchRecordEntry> batchEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i=0; i < entryCount; i++) {
            ACHBatchRecordEntry entry = new ACHBatchRecordEntry(); //populate randomly
            hydrateBatchRecordEntry(entry);
            batchEntries.add(entry);
        }
        
        batch.setAchBatchRecordEntries(batchEntries);
        
        
        return batch;
    }
    
    
    private ACHBatchRecordEntry hydrateBatchRecordEntry(ACHBatchRecordEntry entry) {
        
       
        
        entry.setRecordTypeCode('6');
        entry.setTransactionCode(Long.parseLong(faker.expression("#{options.option '22', '23', '24', '27','28', '29', '32', '33','34', '37', '38', '39','52', '53'}")));
        entry.setReceivingDfiId(Long.parseLong(faker.regexify("(\\d{4})(\\d{4})")));
        entry.setCheckDigit(Integer.parseInt(faker.regexify("(\\d{1})")));
        entry.setDfiAcctNbr(Long.parseLong(faker.regexify("\\d{8,17}")));
        entry.setAmount(Long.parseLong(faker.regexify("\\d{1,8}[0-9]{2}")));
        entry.setIndividualIdNbr(alphameric(faker, 15));
        entry.setIndividualName(alphameric(faker, 22));
        entry.setDiscretionaryData(alphameric(faker, 2));
        entry.setAddendaRecordInd("0"/*faker.expression("#{options.option '0','1'}"*/);
        entry.setTraceNumber(Long.parseLong(/* numeric(faker,15) */faker.regexify("\\d{8}\\d{7}")));
        entry.setPartnerId(null);
        entry.setNetworkId(null);
        entry.setSourceId(null);
        entry.setIsFeeRow(null);
        entry.setNtwrkGroup(null);
        entry.setTypeCrDr(null);
        entry.setIchgPaid(null);
        entry.setIsAudit(null);
        
        globalEntriesCnt = globalEntriesCnt+1;
        
        return entry;
    }
    
    
    private int  getRandomNumberBetween(int min, int max) {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.ints(min, max)
          .findFirst()
          .getAsInt();
    }
    
    private static String alphameric(Faker faker, int length) {
        return faker.regexify("[a-zA-Z0-9]"+"{"+length+"}");
    }
    
    private static String numeric(Faker faker, int length) {
        return faker.regexify("[0-9]"+"{"+length+"}");
    }

}
```

The domain model used in the above is utilizing Lombok to minimize the noise

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
and is succinctly captured by the following diagram:

[image]

Here's the log prior to me forcing the job to end:

[image]

The first few lines of the resulting output file, (though it's expected to be much smaller and not to grow endlessly):

```
101
148443910
50331482322101213258094101Hodkiewicz-Boehm Bank  Ankunding Inc National         
5220Ritchie, Littel                     1393007334PPD   PAYROLL000000221012   1959495220000000
63452521467866465989         0000003935g18HIT965i7ETGWZ62tj1297ZxO8C68X4TRi9P30352152121328313
822066114085109536255975519170430576556960821393007334                         959495220000000
9000001107580000000014851122706212626088862377085717968                                       
101 227431075
21169773022101213253094101Gottlieb and Sons Bank Rau-Stoltenberg Nationa        
5220Tremblay-Jacobi                     1393007334CCD   PAYROLL000000221012   1072720110000000
65229729587541518704         0000000365WCHFwlZZ6Fy12w42K804xanZbg9EQrECfqe14rU0569490215331309
822585225489033627844945756870343498946581941393007334                         072720110000000
9000001643148000000029176494539715791229631730255483996                                       
101 783912452 73446311022101213258094101Lemke LLC Bank         Hartmann Group National        
5220Osinski-Ankundin                    1393007334PPDCHILDSUPPT000000221012   1580365930000000
6232362603079088008083       0000572321mFv70SwjST49Cn61oUmO0RGU1d6GpnF4QOTW4gO0429366510484932
822585780991958244236633184019954769241016981393007334                         580365930000000
9000001979589000000034909147632858521223040297024641339                                       
101540403835
7366241242210121325R094101Batz-Cartwright Bank   Pagac, Lang and Cruicks        
5220McLaughlin LLC                      1393007334PPDTAX PAYMNT000000221012   1828735650000000
627763753739133560955        0215295332UHiB89JHp07Vz103Yk7ak9Uu7ZPU7h20T41lT080447310264016579
822524080519712860312177808514396808331431181393007334                         828735650000000
9000001609029000000048083134068768951025970076873002811                                       
101 805312607 9550255782210121325P094101Rolfson, Dickens and ThHickle-Nikolaus Nationa        
5200Keebler, Beahan                     1393007334CCDCHILDSUPPT000000221012   1411796930000000
6291620437707152548913       0000008009lRiDV09ImX56cFpLa9KH3EGm8pL1B7hXaQYGXJ40374388107061717
822547907303258414717623273017128715262420071393007334                         411796930000000
9000001576193000000050395047885920832708971525878894430                                       
101
774208747 81011974722101213252094101Hauck and Sons Bank    Rutherford, Pouros and         
5200Walsh, Kuphal an                    1393007334PPDTAX PAYMNT000000221012   1712895590000000
6530996980344306789083232    00000092834z6K97b3oCEauKejv8tBAaDwdEc9247PIBqPucU0150021840389603
822555172665696286497679023639445794463558711393007334                         712895590000000
9000001525909000000065651626863895985923314959004431940                                       
101242422683
34477209222101213252094101Wuckert Inc Bank       Weissnat Group National        
5225Gulgowski-Daniel                    1393007334CCDVENDOR PMT000000221012   1107267040000000
634411693383861813994        0000000155PlkhGzhoCKo69rLTVaHZrpk0DplI71HBUmj58490486801505961770
822596698363062230404866793850216599405859231393007334                         107267040000000
9000001449423000000071233345724319150083033332491192973                                       
101 737231663 06274701222101213250094101Kuhlman, D'Amore and SpKessler, Dare and Green        
5225Bradtke-Bosco                       1393007334PPDVENDOR PMT000000221012   1484640460000000
62296396681813672697         0000000299Yxfl1h7J19O4d5X64Z9ZFX1z104ooKtm2VpEx680274086060693183
822048481870472334414769663843886422630313501393007334                         484640460000000
9000001337383000000087376356684923946485931889087698511                                       
101
186612825
9468555472210121325B094101Okuneva Inc Bank       Sipes-Durgan National B        
5220Corkery, Keeling                    1393007334PPD   PAYROLL000000221012   1809674600000000
627715435715184430196        0000670806dBo50VgUra2qQDr87nyKtxIrttQVL54xPZ3HCmO0258779859548925
822575961454518765508879931641082490356796751393007334                         809674600000000
9000001773785000000097303376120373730689833505074581396                                       
101
643404173
```

Not sure what's causing this behavior.  Maybe it's having to do with bean scoping?  Perhaps someone can lead me onto a right track with resolving this.  Also, perhaps there's a better Spring Batch-specific way to produce such fixed length mainframe-styled records?

Much appreciated!

Comment: can you host some sample on github?

if not, you can also take thread dump and see where its waiting.

other thing you can do is set spring logging to debug
eg: `logging.level.org.springframework=debug` 
or if very specific logging is needed you can go with  `logging.level.org.springframework.batch=debug` 
this might get you more insights

Comment: I cannot, conveniently Github is blocked here.  I kind of know where it's waiting, I'm not sure why.  I've already debugged it to get to this point, will do some more of it - thought that people might have encountered similar behavior already and could suggest the right approach.

Comment: Some research also uncovered the fact that this behavior may be due to presence of Spring JPA on the classpath https://www.github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3725 in Spring Boot version 2.3.0.RELEASE. I'm using what seems to be a later Spring Boot (2.7.4) with Batch ver. 4.3.7 and my pom.xml contains no JPA starter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ItemReader should return `null` when no more items remain to be processed, otherwise the Step will continue forever.  So after the `read()` method returns the first time, it should return `null` the next time it is called.

Comment: Thank you.  Can this be backed up by some refs to the doc.  Spring seems to be invoking the read() method so apparently it needs some kind of a flag/condition to indicate to it to stop invoking the read().  Are there standard facilities in Spring Batch to achieve that or am I on the wrong track here?

Comment: @Simeon Leyzerzon This is explained in the reference docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#itemReader and javadocs https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemReader.html. There is no flag to stop reading, the driving step calls the `read` method until it returns null. Returning null *is* the signal to stop reading.